# Eclipse, pydef, python on usb Stick - import doesn't work

Tags: pydev

I did an installation of Portable_Python_2.7.6.1, Eclipse and pydef.
Everything is part of a directory.
Objective: to get everything running without dependence to the PC, to be copied and run from USB stick on different PCs.

Pydef and Eclipse are running with a printed 'hello world'.
As soon as I create an import (e.g. import win32clipboard) I get the error message

> Unresolved import:win32clipboard

in Eclipse and the corresponding

> import win32clipboard ImportError: DLL load failed:

If I run the script from shell out of the directory where the *python.exe* is located it works, if I run the script out from the directory of Eclipse it shows the same error message like inside eclipse.

Do I need to change some setting?

Btw. to start eclipse not with a double click but from bash out of the python directory seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I got it running:

1.) Absolute path of python in pyDev: It seems there is no way out here. So the solution is now a StartEclipseIDE.bat. Here I put the USB Stick to a drive letter by using subst.

2.) second problem was the import of libs are not found if the pyDev starts interpretation out from eclipse directory. Here again the StartEclipseIDE.bat is the solution.
I change the working directory to the PythonPortable (where python.exe is located) and start eclipse from here.

The bat looks like this:

#

subst a: .  #this maps the a drive letter to the current directory
            # all your absolute path is now based on a:\

a:          # change to the new drive
cd a:\pythonPortable  #working directrory to python directory

..\eclipse\eclipse.exe #start eclipse from the working directory.

#

Hoping this helps you.
Now  I have a full python environment ready on a stick